# Python Plotting Data Obtained from Quandl API the Wrong Way?

Tags: python, plot

I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# quandl_data.py

from __future__ import print_function

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import requests


def construct_futures_symbols(
        symbol, start_year=2010, end_year=2016
):
    """
    Constructs a list of futures contract codes
    for a particular symbol and timeframe.
    """
    futures = []
    # March, June, September and
    # December delivery codes
    months = 'HMUZ'
    for y in range(start_year, end_year+1):
        for m in months:
            futures.append("%s%s%s" % (symbol, m, y))
    return futures


def download_contract_from_quandl(contract, dl_dir):
    """
    Download an individual futures contract from Quandl and then
    store it to disk in the 'dl_dir' directory. An auth_token is
    required, which is obtained from the Quandl upon sign-up.
    """
    # Construct the API call from the contract and auth_token
    api_call = "https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/"
    api_call += "CME/%s.csv" % contract
    # If you wish to add an auth token for more downloads, simply
    # comment the following line and replace MY_AUTH_TOKEN with
    # your auth token in the line below
    params = "?sort_order=asc"
    params = "?auth_token=myTokenHere&sort_order=asc"
    full_url = "%s%s" % (api_call, params)

    # Download the data from Quandl
    data = requests.get(full_url).text
    # Store the data to disk
    fc = open('%s/%s.csv' % (dl_dir, contract), 'w')
    fc.write(data)
    fc.close()


def download_historical_contracts(
        symbol, dl_dir, start_year=2010, end_year=2016
    ):
    """
    Downloads all futures contracts for a specified symbol
    between a start_year and an end_year.
    """
    contracts = construct_futures_symbols(
        symbol, start_year, end_year
    )
    for c in contracts:
        print("Downloading contract: %s" % c)
        download_contract_from_quandl(c, dl_dir)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    symbol = 'ES'

    # Make sure you've created this
    # relative directory beforehand
    dl_dir = 'quandl/futures/ES'

    # Create the start and end years
    start_year = 2010
    end_year = 2016

    # Download the contracts into the directory
    download_historical_contracts(
        symbol, dl_dir, start_year, end_year
    )

    # Open up a single contract via read_csv
    # and plot the settle price
    es = pd.io.parsers.read_csv(
        "%s/ESH2010.csv" % dl_dir, index_col="Date"
    )
    es["Settle"].plot()
    plt.show()
```

The code runs without error, however it is plotting in the wrong direction. Seems to be plotting from new to old dates. I would like to plot the oldest data first.

[image: Graph of result]

How do I achieve this? I thought changing the `params = "?sort_order=asc"` to `params = "?sort_order=desc"`, which only changes the .csv file order not the plot.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, i've used the API docs and found the problem.
The parameter you need to use to order the data is: "order=asc|desc", and not "sort_order" as previously thought.

Please use this function:

```
def download_contract_from_quandl(contract, dl_dir):
"""
Download an individual futures contract from Quandl and then
store it to disk in the 'dl_dir' directory. An auth_token is
required, which is obtained from the Quandl upon sign-up.
"""
# Construct the API call from the contract and auth_token
api_call = "https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/"
api_call += "CME/%s.csv" % contract
# If you wish to add an auth token for more downloads, simply
# comment the following line and replace MY_AUTH_TOKEN with
# your auth token in the line below
params = "?auth_token=YOUR_TOKEN"
params += "&order=asc"
full_url = "%s%s" % (api_call, params)

# Download the data from Quandl
data = requests.get(full_url).text
# Store the data to disk
fc = open('%s/%s.csv' % (dl_dir, contract), 'w')
fc.write(data)
```

Note:
The way you are using the api, by simple http request, altough works, is the not the ideal way to use their API.
There is a python package called Quandl, you can install like so:

```
pip3 install quandl
```

On your system.
Also then you would have a single (and not multiple using auth_token=YOUR_TOKEN in each request) auth call like so:

```
quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = 'YOUR_TOEKN'
```

And then each api call will be simple and elegent using their package instead or creating an http request manually, like so:

```
data = quandl.get("CME/ESH2010.csv", order="asc")
```

I will advise using the second method of using the API, but both will work perfectly.

Cheers, Or.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, unfortunately the outcome is the same

Comment: Did you try making them both `desc` instead of `asc`?

Comment: Edited my answer, take a look.

Comment: Edited again. This time your output should be correct.

Comment: @or.ohev-zion Thanks again for your time on this much appreciated. The second option works like a treat! The only problem is I need the AuthToken because that permits me 50,000 API calls per day, the latter only permits 50. I tried the first option but that resulted a New to Old data plot.

Comment: Please reference me to the API site, so we can try and get you a token. It usually is a long string of chars and digits.

Comment: @or.ohev-zion I have a token but your not suposed to hand them out. I have setup a dummy account and you can use this one for tesing puposes "uekh5mpWvJSUzDm7Aqzw"

Comment: @James i've found the issue, and updated my answer, i think it will answer your needs completly.

Comment: @or.ohev-zion You my friend are awesome! Great work. I will look into the Quandl Python package. For now you have satisfied my original question and I have marked your answer as correct.